# Need a substring SQL for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
destination                     rateinitial
------------------------------------------------
Andorra Fixed                       0.01791
Argentina Fixed - Arguello      0.00828
Argentina Fixed - Azcuenaga     0.00942
Argentina Fixed - Bahia Blanca      0.00652
Argentina Fixed - Buenos Aires      0.00518
Argentina Fixed - Campana       0.00828
United Kingdom Fixed    0.00513
United Kingdom Fixed - Jersey   0.00564
United Kingdom Fixed - London   0.00543
United Kingdom Mobile - fm12    0.01046
United Kingdom Mobile - H3G 0.01415
United Kingdom Mobile - O2  0.01415
United Kingdom Mobile - Orange  0.01415
United States - OnNet - AL - 205    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AL - 251    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AL - 256    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AL - 334    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AR - 479    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AR - 501    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AR - 870    0.00502
United States - OnNet - AZ - 480
```

I am looking for a sql query that will display result for country <= 0.01 and not shows duplicates countries

```
Argentina Fixed
United Kingdom Fixed
United States
```

Thanks

Comment: If it's mysql, why not just create more columns and normalize your COUNTRY data?

Comment: it's a complex calling rate database.

Comment: So what if it's complex? Adding a normalized country column will save you a lot of ugly string manipulations in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED2** As per your comments

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(destination, ' - ', 1) country
  FROM table1
 WHERE rateinitial <= 0.01
```

Output:

```
|              COUNTRY |
------------------------
|      Argentina Fixed |
| United Kingdom Fixed |
|        United States |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bab21/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's working just that I am missing "Fixed" or "Mobile". How can I get per example a result like "Argentina Fixed" without the - - Arguello

Comment: @user2378786 You're welcome. See updated answer. Although you should've mentioned this in your question.

Comment: I am ran it and getting 
Argentina Fixed - Arguello
Argentina Fixed - Azcuenaga
Argentina Fixed - Bahia Blanca

How can I just get "Argentina Fixed"?

Comment: @user2378786 Did you see updated sqlfiddle that I provided? If you posted correct data sample it should work. Double check that you use exact code.